# Разделение выводимого списка слов

Tags: php, html, css, таблицы

Есть список слов, который выводится из массива на страницу в виде

```
слово1
слово2
слово3
```

слов много, каждый раз разное количество
необходим код, который разделит весь массив на три столбца, первые два равные, третий чуть меньше, так что во всех трех столбцах помещается весь список

итоговый вид примерно такой

```
слово 1     слово 3       слово 5
слово 2     слово 4
```

через что это лучше и проще всего реализовать вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = array('слово1','слово2','слово3','слово4','слово5');
$column_total_string = ceil((count($arr)/3));

$i = 0; $i_column = 1;
while($i_column <= 3) {
    echo '<div class="column" style="float: left; width: 100px">';
        while(true) {
            echo $arr[$i].'<br>';
            $i++;
            if ($i % $column_total_string == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    echo '</div>';
    $i_column++;
}
```